# Generating substrings in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to generate all the substrings of the word fun.

But it prints "un" two times, I don't know why.

```
int c, i;
    string s = "fun";
    for (c = 0; c < s.length(); c++)
    {
        for (i = c+1; i <= s.length(); i++)
        {
            string d = s.substr(c, i);
            cout << d << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: have another look at the docs for [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). The second argument is *length*, not the after the end index.

Comment: If you use C++, not C you should declare variables in most limited scope as possible.

Comment: @FirstStep Hey, that's my comment!! ;) And don't forget to pass the cv along please.

Comment: The <= is the culprit. C++ uses 0-based indices, which go from 0 to N-1. You are reading the terminating nul on the second pass.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought it is NathanOliver's no?

Comment: @FirstStep A coincide to some degree. It was a joke. Just use that as a stock comment as much you want to use it, feel free. You just ninja'd me here.

Comment: @FirstStep You're welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is length, not the ending `index` of the sub-string.

You can use the following logic to get all sub-strings:

- Start from index `0`, select the substring of length `1`, then of length `2`, then `3` and so on
- Then move on to index `1` and perform the same to it and so on. (When at index `1`, the remaining length of the string would be `2`, in case of `fun`, so we'd have to run the loop till length `2`)

  ```
  string s = "fun";
  for (int c = 0; c < s.length(); c++)
  {
      for (int i = 1; i <= s.length() - c; i++)
      {
          string d = s.substr(c, i);
          cout << d << endl;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> But it prints "un" two times, I don't know why.

you can find why if you print c and i

```
    ...
    for (i = c+1; i <= s.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << "c,i: " << c << i << endl; // add this line to debug !
        string d = s.substr(c, i);
        ...
```

the output:

```
c,i: 01
f
c,i: 02
fu 
c,i: 03
fun
c,i: 12
un
c,i: 13
un
c,i: 23
n
```

Note that, substr will just add as many char as possible after *c*, if *i* is longer than the remaining characters in your string, as per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

> Number of characters to include in the substring (if the string is shorter, as many characters as possible are used).